# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed while using cv2.undistortpoints

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, assertion, calibration

I'm trying to use cv2.undistortpoints function to reproject a point(like (123,321)) from a distort image to it's undistort version. When I code on my ubuntu 18 PC, everything worked well. However when I copy this code to another computer running ubuntu 18, this error message comes out:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.isContinuous() && (src.depth() ==
> 5 || src.depth() == 6) && ((src.rows == 1 && src.channels() == 2) ||
> src.cols*src.channels() == 2)) in undistortPoints, file
> /home/robotics/opencv-3.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/undistort.cpp, line
> 492
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/robotics/catkin_ws/src/img_recog/scripts/sight.py", line 132,
> in 
> b = project_n_undistort(a,world)   File "/home/robotics/catkin_ws/src/img_recog/scripts/sight.py", line 30, in
> project_n_undistort
> b = cv2.undistortPoints(b, mtx, dist, None, mtx) cv2.error: /home/robotics/opencv-3.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/undistort.cpp:492:
> error: (-215) src.isContinuous() && (src.depth() == 5 || src.depth()
> == 6) && ((src.rows == 1 && src.channels() == 2) || src.cols*src.channels() == 2) in function undistortPoints

P.S. this error message is after installed opencv individually. Using default opencv gave a similar error with a different opencv path only.

here's the core code, I will attach full code is needed:

```
def project_n_undistort(a,world):
    b = np.dot(a,world)
    b = b/b[2]
    b = b[0:2]
    b = cv2.undistortPoints(b, mtx, dist, None, mtx)
    b = b[0][0]
    return b

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    inner = np.array([[307.6017761230469, 0, 512, 0], [0, 342.7832641601562, 384, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]])
    outer = np.dot(np.array([[math.cos(math.radians(2)),0,-math.sin(math.radians(2)),0],[0,1,0,0],
        [math.sin(math.radians(2)),0,math.cos(math.radians(2)),0],[0,0,0,1]]),np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,85],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]))
    mtx = np.array([[437.7949802332059, 0, 502.174798617283], [0, 437.0115481181825, 380.0865280376445], [0, 0, 1]])#camera_matrix 1024*768
    dist = np.array([-0.2171050089304354, 0.03583959522345996, 0.0009684942829751926, 0.0006630572393120683, 0])#distortion coefficient 1024*768

    print('Enter current distance(m)')
    dis = float(input())
    i = dis * 1000 + 111.5

    world = np.array([[0],[(i + 93) * math.tan(math.radians(2.85))],[i],[1]])
    a = np.dot(inner,outer)
    b = project_n_undistort(a,world)
```

Familiar problem happened on my ubuntu 16 notebook too, but not on my jetson NX which is running ubuntu 18. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I realized I made a silly mistake: I checked opencv version in a wrong way.
I used `pkg-config --modversion opencv` to check version on the worked PC but whis was incorrect. The right way is first `import cv2` and then `cv2.__version__`!
after I got the right version of opencv which is 4.2.0 and install it, everything goes fine.